# Magento Bundle products created with SOAP v1 API don't show up in frontend

Tags: magento, soap, bundle, product, magento-1.9

### The Problem

I'm creating and updating products in a Magento 1.9 shop using the SOAP v1 API with PHP.
Everything is working as expected, but **bundle products never show up in the frontend**.

If I create a simple product instead everything works just fine.

By now I have programmatically created bundle products that show *exactly* the same data in the backend as a manually created one. However, they don't appear in categories or search.

### What I checked so far

**The created product:**

- is enabled
- is visible (catalog/search)
- is assigned to a category
- is assigned to the right website
- is assigned to the right store view
- is in stock
- has a simple product assigned which

  - has stock
  - is in stock

**I also...**

- disabled the compiler
- tried flushing the cache
- tried reindexing
- manually went to the static product page URL -> bundle product shows up

Is there *anything* else I missed or can check for? I'm really out of ideas and went through everything I could find on Google and SO.

---

### Example API call

This is the data of a particular API call in PHP.

```
$productData = array (
  'category_ids' => array (2),
  'website_ids' => array (1),
  'name' => 'AK 000016 Bundle',
  'description' => 'AK00016 Bundle descr',
  'short_description' => 'AK00016 Bundle short',
  'status' => '1',
  'url_key' => 'AK000016',
  'visibility' => 4,
  'tax_class_id' => 2,
  'stock_data' => array (
     'qty' => '10',
     'is_in_stock' => '1',
     ),
  );

// Attribute-set id 4, store view code 'en'
$client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', 
  array ('bundle', '4', 'AK000016', $productData, 'en'));
```